# Query for filter product by multi attribute and price in Wooecommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I create a query like that:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'pa_color',
            'value' => array('red'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'pa_for',
            'value' => 'Men',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$post = get_posts($args);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($post);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I try to run this code I get nothing. Please help me check this query and how do I get products by attribute and price?. I take meta_key in term_taxonomy table. Many thanks!

Comment: You need to try `tax_query` rather than `meta_query`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot :)